# Above and Over - The comedy begins

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

Michael Swan in his book (http://ielts-house.net/Ebook/Vocabulary/Practical%20English%20usage.pdf - page 3/ page 4) writes about above/over

---

**1) "Higher than": Above or over**

Above and over can both mean "higher than

*Can you see a helicopter* **above/over** *a palace?*

---

Okay, I make a conclusion they are the same here.

**2) "not directly over": above**

We prefer above when one thing is not directly over than another.

*We've got a little house* **above** *the lake*

---

The thing that is meant here, as I can guess, is the house is higher but it's not on the same vertical line with the lake. If there were **"over"** here

*We've got a little house* **over** *the lake*

then we would have to understand it like the house is hovering/levitating above the lake with no logical explanation. Am thinking right?

This case I am feeling troubled because in the first way of usage the choice of **above/over** means the same thing while in the second one it's different.

Having read the second usage, should I take

*Can you see a helicopter* **above** *a palace?*

like the helicopter is at a higher position than the palace but it is not directly over the building?
And should I understand

*Can you see a helicopter* **over** *a palace?*

like it's right over the roof that if it goes down it will land exactly onto the top of the palace?

I see it as a problem because the author firstly says they are equal but then gives an example with an explanation where they are different.
How should I distinguish the first usage senteces where they are the same from the second usage sentences where they would mean a different thing?

Comment: I suggest you look at some dictionary definitions of the two words. It is much more complicated than the minor inconsistency you see here, and the same thing applies to hundreds of other prepositions.

Comment: [come to the conclusion or conclude and helicopter over the palace, here].